# Xquery extract tags' opening declaration

Tags: xml, xquery

I have following XML:

```
<RULES>
    <TRAP name="trap1" oid=".1.2.3">
      <VAR_LIST>
        <VAR name="var1" value=".1.2.3.1"/>
        <VAR name="var2" value=".1.2.3.2"/>
      </VAR_LIST>
    </TRAP>
    <TRAP name="trap2" oid=".1.2.4">
        ...
    </TRAP>
    ...
</RULES>
```

I would like to generate flattened summary so I iterate through it as follows:

```
for $trap in /RULES/TRAP
    for $var in $rule/VAR_LIST/VAR
       return (opening-tag-declaration($trap), opening-tag-declaration($var), "&#10;")
```

I would like to get following output, but I don't know how to extract tag's opening declaration only...

```
<TRAP name="trap1" oid=".1.2.3> <VAR name="var1" value=".1.2.3.1"/>
<TRAP name="trap1" oid=".1.2.3> <VAR name="var2" value=".1.2.3.2"/>
<TRAP name="trap2" oid=".1.2.4> ...
...
```

Comment: In your result XML example you forgot the closing `</TRAP>` tags.

Comment: The result wasn't consider to be a valid XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to define `opening-tag-declaration` (adapted from [this function](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_remove-elements.html) in the FunctX library):

```
declare namespace example = "http://example.com";
declare function example:opening-tag-declaration 
    ( $elements as element()* ) as element()* {

    for $element in $elements
        return element
            {node-name($element)}
            {$element/@* }
};
```

It includes the element name and its attributes in the resulting element, but not the child nodes. [Demo](http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#dY19u2nz0mqDFDTQWgWarJ9PVE8=) using the [books.xml](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/books.xml) example file from w3schools.

Answer (score 0):

This is my custom approach to this problem before [mgibsonbr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520779/mgibsonbr) answer:

```
declare function local:tag($node as node()) as xs:string {
    concat(substring-before(fn:serialize($node), ">"), ">")
};
```